# SSRS 2008R2 Report not displaying with IE 11 in load balanced environment.

Tags: reporting-services, internet-explorer-11, ssrs-2008-r2, nlb

In our project we are using SSRS 2008R2 reports, unfortunately no time has been invested into upgrading these nor will there be, so I am stuck dragging these along for now, and have little experience with them.

In Chrome and Firefox all of the below scenarios work, however IE11 does not.
The architecture is this:

We have multiple web servers and 1 Report server.
The web servers are load balanced, so use a common host name.

If I don't use the host name and instead call straight from browser to webserver which then calls report server, report displays ok on browser.

If I use the load balancer host name to call webserver which then calls report server it doesn't display the report.

There are no javascript errors and nothing in the event logs on the servers.
It just doesn't display in IE11 using the load balancer host name.

It doesn't seem to be a configuration issue as it works with chrome and firefox when using the host name.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Can you check the security settings of both URLs? Are they in the same zone? Can you also check if 1 of them is using compatibility view?

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me, much appreciated. Neither of them is using compatibility view, can you elaborate on the statement "Are they in the same zone"? the load balancer is on a Linxu centos 6.5 box, the others are all Windows 2008 R2. They are all within the one domain if thats what you mean.

Comment: I'm talking about the `Security` tab in IE `Internet Options`, on the client computers.

Comment: Hi Sebastien both sites are in Internet zone, I tried adding to trusted sites but hasn't made a difference, report still not shown.

Comment: I'm asking all these questions because it works on other browsers while not working with IE, so it could be a different configuration between one URL and the other. I will throw other ideas on the top of my head: Is there a proxy configured? Have you tried with different client computers? Can you try with another IE version if all client computers have the same reult?

Comment: Thanks, however none of these worked, doing a bit of head scratching on this one.